# What does it mean to explain variance?

Tags: multiple-regression

In particular, I am wondering why we have this concept Multiple R (which I can understand as the correlation between observed and predicted scores in multiple regression), and then a separate concept R-squared which is just the square or R.

I've been informed that R-squared is the percentage variation explained and R is not, but I don't understand the distinction that is being made between correlation and explained variation.

Comment: One of my greatest teachers recounted his PhD thesis defence in which he explained to a group of physical oceanographers that his regression could explain XX% of the variation in some data. A distinguished examiner stood up and proclaimed "With your correlations you have explained exactly nothing; rather you have offered us a suggestion which falls apart 10% of the time"

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90793/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-r-and-r-squared

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A main issue here is that the measure of "variation" in regression analysis is related to the *squared* differences of observed variables from their predicted mean values. This is a useful choice of a measure of variation, both for theoretical analysis and in practical work, because squared differences from the mean are related to the variance of a random variable, and the variance of the sum of two independent random variables is simply the sum of their individual variances.

$R^2$ in multiple regression represents the fraction of "variation" in the observed variable that is accounted for by the regression model when *squared* differences from predicted means are used as the measure of variation. The Multiple R is simply the square root of $R^2$.

I'm afraid that I've never understood the usefulness of specifying the value of the Multiple R rather than $R^2$. Unlike the correlation coefficient $r$ in a univariate regression, which shows both the direction and strength of the relation between 2 variables, specifying the Multiple R doesn't seem to add much beyond a chance for additional confusion.