# Why are "Proportion of variance explained"s similar for all the methods in the Package relaimpo?

Tags: r, regression, r-squared

In package `relaimpo` in `R`, we measure the relative importance with different methods. However, the $R^2$ for all the methods is similar.

Is it supposed to be similar or a bug?

Comment: What do you measure? For what methods? What is your data, what models do you compare?

Comment: I measure the relative importance of some variables. Relaimpo package has a range of methods  which are c("lmg", "pmvd", "last", "first", "betasq", "pratt", "genizi", "car"). I hoped that using different methods give me different coefficient of determination but it is not true. Wondering if I'm missing something or it is a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) measures fit of the *model*, not of particular variables.

From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/relaimpo.pdf) (bold added by myself):

> Five of the metrics in `calc.relimp` (`lmg`, `pmvd`, `pratt`, `genizi`
>   and `car`), **decompose the model $R^2$**. `calc.relimp` (`lmg`,
>   `pmvd`, `pratt`, `genizi` and `car`) sum to the $R^2$ that is to be
>   decomposed [...]

You can find out more about the methods from the references provided in the documentation.

Notice however that $R^2$ [can be misleading](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous) and [does not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226509/how-to-find-variance-in-explained-within-the-output-coefficients/226524#226524) really tell you about "variance explained" unless you are using linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, do you have any idea if there is a way to compare theses methods? In my case, there are different weights  in different methods? How do I know which one is more accurate?

Comment: What models? You use "methods", "models" and "variables" interchangeably what makes it unclear what do you mean. Do you compare different models? What models?

Comment: @Eddie: The different importance metrics each purport to replace our fuzzy, qualitative notion of "importance" with something exact & quantitative. The question of their accuracy doesn't arise.

Comment: Thanks Scortchi, It's making more sense to me now. How people know which metrics they need to use in practice? Is it anyway to make these metrics actionable?