# Reporting correct CFA figure

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, reporting

I am trying to understand what exactly to report in my final Confirmatory Factor Analysis figure. I plan on reporting standardised estimates with Squared multiple correlations. I am unsure what to report on the figure for the residual error variance, as I can only access these in unstandardised form. Is there a rule-of-thumb for reporting here that I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: A useful reference on what to report for publication purposes is Hancock & Mueller's The Reviewer’s Guide to Quantitative Methods in the Social Sciences.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, people report the full standardized solution, including factor variance(s), factor loadings and residuals. I'm surprised that your software doesn't provide the standardized residuals or have an option to do so. Finally, if you have multiple factors, then correlations between the factors should be provided as well.

Also, what do you mean squared multiple correlations? Usually the R-square is reported, which slightly different in emphasis (see [What's the difference between multiple R and R squared?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90793/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-r-and-r-squared))